# Upload video to server by using Alamofire

Tags: swift, xcode, swift2, alamofire

I used alamofire to upload the chosen image to the server and It's working but now I don't know how I can make the same thing for the selected video from device after select it and store the path of this video at variable , how I can use alamofire to upload this video to server ?

My code:

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import AVKit
import AVFoundation
import MediaPlayer
import MobileCoreServices

class sendFinalNews: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate  {

@IBOutlet weak var titleText: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var msgDetailText: UITextView!
@IBOutlet weak var sendIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView!
@IBOutlet weak var loadedImage: UIImageView!

var CUSTOMER_KEY = "dkeqnq9fmkhq"
var titlemsg = ""
var detailmsg = ""

var videoURL:String!


var playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
var playerView = AVPlayer()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}

@IBAction func addVideoButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    var videoPickerController = UIImagePickerController()
    videoPickerController.delegate = self

    videoPickerController.sourceType = .SavedPhotosAlbum
    videoPickerController.mediaTypes =  [kUTTypeMovie as String]



    self.presentViewController(videoPickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
@IBAction func addImageButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    let ImagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
    ImagePicker.delegate = self
    ImagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary

    self.presentViewController(ImagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}



func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
    let mediaType = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaType] as! NSString

    let url = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL]
    print(url)
    if mediaType.isEqualToString(kUTTypeImage as String)
    {

        loadedImage.image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage


    }
    else if mediaType.isEqualToString(kUTTypeMovie  as String)
    {
        let urlOfVideo = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] as? NSURL
        if let url = urlOfVideo {

            print("video loadaed")
            videoURL = String(urlOfVideo)
            print(videoURL)


        }

    }



    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil )
}


@IBAction func backButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil )

}
@IBAction func sendButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    titlemsg = titleText.text!
    detailmsg = msgDetailText.text!

    self.sendIndicator.startAnimating()

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), { () -> Void in

        // ...
        // heavy loop codes here
        // ...

        self.uploadFile()

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
            self.sendIndicator.stopAnimating()
        })
    });
}



func uploadFile()  {

    //let image = UIImage(named: "ios9.jpg")
    let newimage : NSData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(loadedImage.image!, 32)!

    let newRandomName = randomStringWithLength(32)
    let fname = (newRandomName as String) + ".jpg"

    let parameters = [
        "pic"           :NetData(data: newimage, mimeType: .ImageJpeg, filename: fname),
        "msg"     :self.detailmsg,
        "customer_key" : self.CUSTOMER_KEY
    ]



    let urlRequest = self.urlRequestWithComponents("myURLhere", parameters: parameters)

    Alamofire.upload(urlRequest.0, data: urlRequest.1)
        .progress { (bytesWritten, totalBytesWritten, totalBytesExpectedToWrite) in
            print("\(totalBytesWritten) / \(totalBytesExpectedToWrite)")
        }
        .responseJSON { response in
            debugPrint(response)
    }

}


func urlRequestWithComponents(urlString:String, parameters:NSDictionary) -> (URLRequestConvertible, NSData) {

    // create url request to send
    let mutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: urlString)!)
    mutableURLRequest.HTTPMethod = Alamofire.Method.POST.rawValue
    //let boundaryConstant = "myRandomBoundary12345"
    let boundaryConstant = "NET-POST-boundary-\(arc4random())-\(arc4random())"
    let contentType = "multipart/form-data;boundary="+boundaryConstant
    mutableURLRequest.setValue(contentType, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")


    // create upload data to send
    let uploadData = NSMutableData()

    // add parameters
    for (key, value) in parameters {

        uploadData.appendData("\r\n--\(boundaryConstant)\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)

        if value is NetData {
            // add image
            let postData = value as! NetData


            //uploadData.appendData("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(key)\"; filename=\"\(postData.filename)\"\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)

            // append content disposition
            let filenameClause = " filename=\"\(postData.filename)\""
            let contentDispositionString = "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(key)\";\(filenameClause)\r\n"
            let contentDispositionData = contentDispositionString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            uploadData.appendData(contentDispositionData!)


            // append content type
            //uploadData.appendData("Content-Type: image/png\r\n\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!) // mark this.
            let contentTypeString = "Content-Type: \(postData.mimeType.getString())\r\n\r\n"
            let contentTypeData = contentTypeString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            uploadData.appendData(contentTypeData!)
            uploadData.appendData(postData.data)

        }else{
            uploadData.appendData("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(key)\"\r\n\r\n\(value)".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
        }
    }
    uploadData.appendData("\r\n--\(boundaryConstant)--\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)



    return (Alamofire.ParameterEncoding.URL.encode(mutableURLRequest, parameters: nil).0, uploadData)
}


func randomStringWithLength (len : Int) -> NSString {

    let letters : NSString = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"

    var randomString : NSMutableString = NSMutableString(capacity: len)

    for (var i=0; i < len; i++){
        var length = UInt32 (letters.length)
        var rand = arc4random_uniform(length)
        randomString.appendFormat("%C", letters.characterAtIndex(Int(rand)))
    }

    return randomString

}


}
```

NetData class:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

enum MimeType: String {
case ImageJpeg = "image/jpeg"
case ImagePng = "image/png"
case ImageGif = "image/gif"
case Json = "application/json"
case Unknown = ""

func getString() -> String? {
    switch self {
    case .ImagePng:
        fallthrough
    case .ImageJpeg:
        fallthrough
    case .ImageGif:
        fallthrough
    case .Json:
        return self.rawValue
    case .Unknown:
        fallthrough
    default:
        return nil
    }
}
}

class NetData
 {
let data: NSData
let mimeType: MimeType
let filename: String

init(data: NSData, mimeType: MimeType, filename: String) {
    self.data = data
    self.mimeType = mimeType
    self.filename = filename
}

init(pngImage: UIImage, filename: String) {
    data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(pngImage)!
    self.mimeType = MimeType.ImagePng
    self.filename = filename
}

init(jpegImage: UIImage, compressionQuanlity: CGFloat, filename: String) {
    data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(jpegImage, compressionQuanlity)!
    self.mimeType = MimeType.ImageJpeg
    self.filename = filename
}
}
```